# Using sql function min() in php loop

Tags: php, sql, min, minimum

I have to output some products from table 'products', along with the lowest price from the table 'product_licenses', which is the only column I need from that table in this query.

However, when I try to use the sql function MIN(), my loop only runs through the code once and gets the first result and then it stops, so I am a bit lost here.

This is the query using min() :

```
$mysql->query("
    SELECT pd.*, min(lc.price) AS price
    FROM `products` AS pd, product_licenses AS lc
    WHERE pd.`status` = '1' AND lc.product_id = pd.id
    ORDER BY pd.`id` ASC
    $limitQuery
");
```

I'm using this function to get the products, but this, unfortunately, fetches the highest price:

```
public function getAllProducts($start = 0, $limit = 0, $order = '`datetime` ASC') {
    global $mysql;


    $limitQuery = '';
    if ($limit != 0) {
        $limitQuery = " LIMIT $start,$limit ";
    }
    **// Not working if I use min() on lc.price**
    $mysql->query("
        SELECT pd.*, lc.price
        FROM `products` AS pd, product_licenses AS lc
        WHERE pd.`status` = '1' AND lc.product_id = pd.id
        ORDER BY pd.`id` ASC
        $limitQuery
    ");

    if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->usersWhere = '';
    $return = array();
    while ($d = $mysql->fetch_array()) {
        $categories = explode(',', $d['category_id']);
        unset($d['category_id']);
        foreach ($categories as $c) {
            $c = trim($c);
            if ($c != '') {
                $d['category_id'][$c] = $c;
            }
        }

        $return[$d['id']] = $d;
    }

    $this->foundRows = $mysql->getFoundRows();

return $return;
}
```

Comment: How many rows are returned when you remove `min()`?

Comment: You should debug your query into your database before posting a question here

Comment: does your query gives exact result?

Comment: I think using `min` is supposed to return only one result. This page might help your situation: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/min.php

Comment: Why do you fetch one row at a time, versus using [`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)?

Comment: your query returns only one result since your are using aggregate function but not grouping it.

Comment: As many already said that. If you use `min` or `max` you need to add `group by` to your query. Otherwise you won't get the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `GROUP BY` in your query. your current query returns only one result since your are using aggregate function (**MIN**) but not grouping it.

```
SELECT  pd.col1, 
        pd.col2, min(lc.price) AS PRICE
FROM   `products` AS pd
             INNER JOIN product_licenses AS lc
                  ON lc.product_id = pd.id
WHERE    pd.`status` = '1' 
GROUP BY pd.col1, pd.col2, pd.col3
ORDER BY pd.`id` ASC
$limitQuery
```

***PS: post the structure of your database with records. It will the community understands your question clearly :)***

Comment: If it wasn't posted in the same minute, I could have sworn our queries were *identical*. +1 :)

Comment: You didn't have to, all the answers were right, I upvoted yours and Eric's as they were correct. I just thought it was hilarious that we both did three cols from pd and both use lower case commands such as `group by` when typing. Love your work and look up to to your answers, you have fantastic ones! (Trying to say I wasn't being a jerk, just you gave me a damned good laugh)

Answer (score 4):

You have no `group by` clause in your query, so the query is returning the first row only.

```
SELECT pd.col1, pd.col2, pd.col3,  min(lc.price) AS price
FROM `products` AS pd, product_licenses AS lc
WHERE pd.`status` = '1' AND lc.product_id = pd.id
group by pd.col1, pd.col2, pd.col3
ORDER BY pd.`id` ASC
$limitQuery
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a `GROUP BY` in there, like so:

```
SELECT pd.*, min(lc.price) AS price
FROM `products` AS pd, product_licenses AS lc
WHERE pd.`status` = '1' AND lc.product_id = pd.id
GROUP BY pd.`id`
ORDER BY pd.`id` ASC
$limitQuery
```

Note that with MySQL, you only need to group by the id column even though you are selecting other columns from the products table.

Comment: Thank you so much. Was getting really frustrated about this, but now everything is fine :-)